# how to load local .css file in web view in winrt c#

Tags: c#, html, css, windows-runtime

I have one .html file , respective .css file and some images in local folder.
If i open this .html file in any browser then it's working fine (.css and all images are showing properly).
But when i open this in my winrt 8.1 app , only html file is getting load to webview. css and all images is not getting load in my webview.

my code is below:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "myfile.xhtml";
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        string str=await PathIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile.Path);
        webview.NavigateToString(str);
    }
```